# n clicks, n times repeating the click function , why?

Tags: jquery, click, repeat

Hi i am using this code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var number = 1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /* The button to see the single portfolio items */
jQuery('.cover a').unbind("click").click(function (coverclick){

    coverclick.preventDefault();
    coverclick.stopPropagation();
    coverclick.stopImmediatePropagation();
    number ++;
    /* Get the link */
    var coverlink = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.loadmask').show();
    jQuery('.loadmask-msg').show();
    jQuery('.upperdiv').animate({height : 'hide', opacity : 'hide', easing:   'EaseOutBounce'},'slow', function(){                                      jQuery('.upperdiv').html('');});
    jQuery('.upperdiv').load(coverlink+' .loading_div');
    jQuery('.upperdiv').ajaxComplete(function() {
        var  slideClass = 'all_project_images' + number;
        var  dentroClass = '.' + slideClass;
        jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top},
                    'slow');
        jQuery('.post_nav_portfolio').show();
        jQuery('.slideshow ul').removeClass().addClass(slideClass);
        jQuery(dentroClass).stop(false,true).responsiveSlides({
                    auto: true,
                    nav: true,
                    speed: 500});   
        jQuery('.upperdiv').animate({height : 'show', opacity : 'show', easing: 'EaseInBounce'},'slow');
        jQuery('.loadmask').hide();
        jQuery('.loadmask-msg').hide();
        jQuery('.cover').hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.mimo_portfolio_image').stop().animate({opacity : 0.5},'fast');
                    }, function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.mimo_portfolio_image').stop().animate({opacity : 1},'fast');
                    }); 
        jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        jQuery('.slideshow').hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.rslides_nav').show('slow');
                }, function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.rslides_nav').hide('slow');
            });
            console.log(dentroClass);

            });

    return false;

});

    });
```

to load and show a portfolio item, it loads and works great but i have a duplicating problem, with the
       console.log(dentroClass);

i can see that first click it log 1 time the variable, second click logs 2 times, 3 click log 3 times, well all the functions repeats the number of the click, if it is fifth click it repeats 5 times the function.

I have been working with on(); and OFF(); and bind(); unbind(); but nothing works.

Comment: A quick protip: if you're not using any other external library that uses the $, you should refer to jQuery with $. example: `$('.loadmask').show();`

Comment: Thank you, i have done it but every time i refer like that nothing works..?¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are binding new `ajaxComplete` and `hover` handlers every time you click.

you should move all of those bindings to outside the click function. (so that they will run only once.)

or unbind everything at the beginning of each click.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! I have a little question that i have separated just to give new points if you want here, well the system doesn´t let me post more question for now:  Hi i havan AjaxComplete function in a js file that fires several clicks for different buttons, but all refered to the same selector.

I need a different ajaxComplete function for every click function, is this possible?

Comment: Here you got the question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756211/ajaxcomplete-for-only-a-function-not-a-selector)