# AjaxComplete() for only a function, not a selector

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

Hi i have a AjaxComplete function in a js file that fires several clicks for different buttons, but all refered to the same selector.

I need a different ajaxComplete function for every click function, is this possible?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var number = 1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* The button to see the single portfolio items */
jQuery(document).on('click','.cover a, .prev_mimo, .next_mimo',function (coverclick){

    coverclick.preventDefault();
    coverclick.stopPropagation();
    coverclick.stopImmediatePropagation();
    number ++;
    /* Get the link */
    var coverlink = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.loadmask').show();
    jQuery('.loadmask-msg').show();
    jQuery('.upperdiv').animate({height : 'hide', opacity : 'hide', easing: 'EaseOutBounce'},'slow', function(){                                        jQuery('.upperdiv').html('');});
    jQuery('.upperdiv').load(coverlink+' .loading_div');


    return false;

});
jQuery('.upperdiv').ajaxComplete(function() {
        var  slideClass = 'all_project_images' + number;
        var  dentroClass = '.' + slideClass;
        jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery(this).offset().top},
                    'slow');
        jQuery('.post_nav_portfolio').show();
        jQuery('.slideshow ul').removeClass().addClass(slideClass);
        jQuery(dentroClass).stop(false,true).responsiveSlides({
                    auto: true,
                    nav: true,
                    speed: 500});   
        jQuery('.upperdiv').animate({height : 'show', opacity : 'show', easing: 'EaseInBounce'},'slow');
        jQuery('.loadmask').hide();
        jQuery('.loadmask-msg').hide();
        jQuery('.cover').hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.mimo_portfolio_image').stop().animate({opacity : 0.5},'fast');
                    }, function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.mimo_portfolio_image').stop().animate({opacity : 1},'fast');
                    }); 
        jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        jQuery('.slideshow').hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.rslides_nav').show('slow');
                }, function(){
                jQuery(this).children('.rslides_nav').hide('slow');
            });
            console.log(dentroClass);

            });

      });
```

Comment: ajaxComplete doesn't have anything to do with the click handlers. In any case, it *is* possible to register more than one ajaxComplete handler - try it.

Comment: Could you explain me how to do that? "register more than one ajaxComplete handler" ?¿? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

inside your `ajaxComplete()` function you can check which was the original button that initiated the ajax call, by testing out `$(this)`.

Try something like this:

```
 $('.buttons').ajaxComplete(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('button1')){
         // do one thing
      }else if($(this).hasClass('button2')){
         // do another
      }
 });
```

in this case, your buttons should have different classes to describe their actions:

```
<button class="buttons button1">button1</button>
<button class="buttons button2">button2</button>
```

Comment: But..in this case .buttons is my .upperdiv?? or do i have to give a secondary buttons class to my buttons and then look for the one that was clicked?If i use jQuery('.cover a').ajaxComplete(); it doesn´t work

Comment: just some type of identification (like class) to every button, so you can know which button was clicked, and then do different actions using the if. it doesn't have to be a button like in my example

Comment: I cannot get this to work using "$('.buttons')". It only works when I use rather than "$(document)". Am I missing something?

Comment: I think ajaxComplete method sets a global ajax handler. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930807/1835147