# Can I listen to a specific element on ajaxComplete instead of 'document'?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good morning,

I am using the jQuery ajaxComplete Function and I wonder if it would be possible to use it on a specific element (div)?

Example:

```
<div id="myAjaxDiv"></div>
```

So, if any ajax operation is done in this specific div, I'd like to fire an event.

I would like to use anything like

```
$("#myAjaxDiv").ajaxComplete(function() {
    // my Scripts
})
```

instead of

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // my Scripts
})
```

But, this doesn't work for me :-(
Is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, can you explain, why you want it that way

Comment: I get some database information by ajax in that div. when done I have to check for specific values and change some other form fields on that page

Comment: The perfect answer of your question is given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051276/how-to-know-which-element-in-body-triggered-ajax-request-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AjaxComplete method sets a global ajax hadler, which fires whenever any ajax call completed.
Ajax requests are not bound to any element, so you can't use ajaxComplete on element.
I suggest you to add complete handler directly into your ajax call like

```
$.ajax({
    //...your options
    complete: function(){
        //..your complete logic
    }
});
```

Best regards. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 13):

yes, you can add specified option for $.ajax action, ie:

```
$.ajax({
    my_option : 'somevalue',
    complete: function(){
        //..your complete logic
    }
});
```

and then:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,options){
   //if(options.my_option == 'somevalue') { or:
     if(options.my_option) {
          //..your logic
     }
});
```

good luck :)

Comment: is it possible to pass that custom parameter with the .load method?
`$("#myDiv").load("page2.php");`

Answer (score 0):

While you can't call the unknown form, you can do as I did and create an "Ajax Wrapper" and use a complete handler here which when invoked by the wrapper, will give you ajaxComplete functionality with the desired addition. It has the advantage of condensing code, while not affecting capability. The disadvantage is a small amount of performance overhead.

Define all the defaults you want within the function. I like this because I use some near-global success/error handles for dialogs.

```
function ajaxWrapper(srcForm,overrides) {
  var ret = $.extend(true,{type: "POST",
    url: $(srcForm).attr('action'),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
        tzOffset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
    },
    success: // success handler,
    error: // error handler,
    beforeSend: function(jqXhr,plainObject) {
        $(srcForm).find("button[type=submit], button[type=reset], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]").prop("disabled", true);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $(srcForm).find("button[type=submit], button[type=reset], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  },overrides);
  $.ajax(ret);
}
```

It uses [`$.extend(true,,)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)  to merge the objects. `True` sends it to a deep copy enabling both objects to have a `data` object and inheriting properties from both, while overriding in favor of `overrides` where the two object's `data` might conflict.

If you don't want an override, **remove `true,`. False is not supported, as per the current docs.**

I call the function like simple as this

```
ajaxWrapper($(this),{url: $(this).attr('action'), // I choose to leave action in just to make clear to me where this ajax is submitting
    data: {ObjectID: $('#myID').val(),
        f1: $('#f1').val(),
        f2: $('#f2').val(),
        someCheckbox: $('#someCheckbox').prop('checked')}
});
```