# jQuery, hide a before element

Tags: jquery, css

ADD TO BAG button changes it's text to ADDED +icon :before{content: '\2713';} when clicked.

Then after 4 seconds reverts text to ADD TO BAG, I mean from Added to Add to bag again.

The ADD TO BAG normal button text has no icon and the ADDED text has an icon.

Problem: once the text changes to ADDED +icon, it then reverts to ADD TO BAG but together with its icon, how can I exclude the icon?

I am trying to revert the Added text to Add to bag without the icon.

Following is my jQuery code that is working and what I have tried and also the CSS code.

//working jQuery code

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var element = jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added");
    element.text("ADDED");
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.text("ADD TO BAG");
        element.css('background-color', '#F0EFEB');
        element.css('color', '#A9885D');
    }, 4 * 1000);
});
```

//I have tried this

`element.before('visibility', 'hiden');`  but it hides the whole button.

CSS code for the icon -

```
.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added:before 
{
    content: '\2713';
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

if I simply remove this CSS code then I won't have the icon on ADDED text, which is a green tick icon unless there is another way I am not seeing now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is to remove ".added" class.

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    var element = jQuery("a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart.added");
    element.text("ADDED");
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.text("ADD TO BAG");
        element.css('background-color', '#F0EFEB');
        element.css('color', '#A9885D');
        //remove added class from element
        element.removeClass("added");
    }, 4 * 1000);
});
```

Also i have to say to watchout on that `jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(...)` because that function will be executed on any complete ajax request on that page.

Comment: Thank you @Giacomo! you are right it is applying to all completed buttons. How to avoid pls?

Comment: You're wellcome. Actually i generally would avoid to listen for events at document level, that can lead to your situation or similar situation in future.
There are more reliable code construct in javascript like callbacks and promises.
In this use case a callback in that specific ajax request would be fine.
Here is how to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930653/can-i-listen-to-a-specific-element-on-ajaxcomplete-instead-of-document
Jquery Ajax Docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/